# Read-only file system error in Kubernetes POD

Tags: linux, kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-pod

I have deployed the Kubernetes pod through the deployment file. While checking the logs, all the volumeMount inside the pod are read-only permission which throws an error and the application is not properly working as expected.

command: Kubectl exec -it pod_name -n namespace -- /bin/bash

Trying to do some Linux operations such as `chmod`, `ls`, `cp`, `mv` is not working and throws with permission denied error.

Ex:

```
chmod: changing permissions of 'ssl_keycloak_keygen.sh': Read-only file system
writing new private key to '/ssl-certificates/portal-tls.key'
req: Can't open "/ssl-certificates/portal-tls.key" for writing, Permission denied
cp: cannot stat 'xxx.key': No such file or directory
```

#### Tried solutions:

1. Have tried changing securitycontext fsgroup, runasuser inside deployment file
2. Added group member as root inside docker file before building an image
3. setenuser 0 in linux machine

Above solution doesnt work, kindly let me know if you have some solutions.

```
Deployment file Sample:
spec:
      volumes:
        - name: s1
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: s1-pvc-rwx
        - name: configmap-volume
          configMap:
            name: keycloak-config1
            defaultMode: 511
      containers:
        - resources: {}
          name: keycloak
          env:
          - xxxx-- not mentioned
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
            - name: sslfolder
              mountPath: /sslfolder
            - name: configmap-volume
              mountPath: /opt/jboss/ssl_keycloak_keygen.sh
              subPath: ssl_keycloak_keygen.sh
```

PV:

```
kind: PersistentVolume 
apiVersion: v1 
metadata:
 name: volume1
 labels:
  type: ocs
spec: 
 storageClassName: xxx 
 capacity:
  storage: 3Gi
 accessModes:
 - ReadWriteMany 
 hostPath:
  path: "/mnt/k8s/vol1"
```

PVC:

```
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
 metadata:
  name: sslxxx
 spec:
  accessModes: 
  - ReadWriteMany 
  volumeMode: Filesystem 
  resources: 
   requests:
    storage: 1Gi
  storageClassName: xxx
```

Comment: use the init container to change the permission and move the files.

Comment: Hi @HarshManvar, i have tried that as well by providing privileged=true and also fsgroup as well. Not working as expected. When I check the id inside the pod, everything is on root user only.

Comment: how your pv getting created is it statefulset or manually creating pv by applying yaml ?

Comment: It is created through yaml file.

Comment: Could you share the information about the pvc/pv ? `kubectl get pv/xxx && kubectl get pvc/xxx`

Comment: [root]# kubectl get pv
NAME          CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM                                       
volume1       3Gi        RWX            Retain           Bound       ssl-pvc-rwx                               
[root]# kubectl get pvc
NAME                  STATUS   VOLUME     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
ssl-pvc-rwx           Bound    volume1    3Gi        RWX            XXX            20h

Answer (score 0):

I assume Your PVC is marked as read-only, please paste your PV/PVC definition and verify that you can set it to RW

#### `PersistentVolume`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: test-volume
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 400Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce <----------------
```

#### `PersistentVolumeClaim`

```yaml
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  # in this demo we use GCP so we are using the 'standard' StorageClass
  # We can of course define our own StorageClass resource
  storageClassName: standard

  # The access modes are:
  #   ReadWriteOnce - The volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node
  #   ReadWriteMany - The volume can be mounted as read-write by a many node
  #   ReadOnlyMany  - The volume can be mounted as read-only  by many nodes
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Comment: PV:
---

kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: volume1
  labels:
    type: ocs
spec:
  storageClassName: xxx
  capacity:
    storage: 3Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/k8s/vol1"


PVC:
-----
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: sslxxx

spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  storageClassName: xxx

Comment: PV set as ReadWriteMany and PVC set as ReadWriteMany only.

Answer (score 0):

From your error message:

```
req: Can't open "/ssl-certificates/portal-tls.key" for writing, Permission denied
```

the script is failing to write to **/ssl-certificates**

But in your pod.spec you're mounting the pvc in a different path

```
 volumeMounts:
            - name: sslfolder
              mountPath: /sslfolder
```

So you're trying to write to the wrong location. Try updating either your volumeMount, or the location your script is writing to and this should be fine. PVCs will be mounted read-write by default, unless you add a read-only option in your mount.

Comment: Hi @trmathe, i am using ssl-certificates only, for sharing purpose, i am modifying it.. It is correctly mapped to ssl-certificates ony.

Comment: I see some problem with config volume which gives as read only permission. I am not sure how to overcome that

Comment: Hiya. Can you kubectl exec into the pod and run: `touch /sslfolder/test` to see if that works?